# Why using static arrays rather than dynamics arrays?

Tags: c++

I know that, in C++, there is 2 kind of arrays : statics and dynamics arrays. But I have a question :

Why would we use static arrays rather than dynamics arrays in some cases whereas, it seems to me, we can do more things with dynamics arrays than with statics arrays ?

Why would we use dynamics arrays in all cases ?

Comment: One reason is that they require a dynamic memory allocation, which may be considered too costly. Also, they have to be de-allocated manually, and this is easy to mess up. The latter problem can be avoided by using e.g. `std::vector`.

Comment: Dynamic arrays generally carry more overhead (an extra level of indirection, at least).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15062767/heap-dynamic-vs-static-memory-allocation-for-c-singleton-class-instance

Comment: @juanchopanza _'which may be considered too costly'_ or simply aren't available for the platform (which is one of my daily bread & butter) ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I guess it would be too costly to use another platform then :-)

Comment: @juanchopanza It boils down there essentially, yes :). But I'm still enjoying (meta-)programming c++ applications on a small Cortex-M3 and see the baffled faces of all our c-gurus ;-) ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why would we use static arrays rather than dynamics arrays in some cases whereas, it seems to me, we can do more things with dynamics arrays than with statics arrays ?

Assuming that with *static arrays* you mean C-style arrays or `std::array` and with *dynamic arrays* you mean `std::vector`, because:

1. static arrays can be optimized by the compiler, since the size in known at compile time.
2. dynamic arrays make use of dynamic memory allocation, which can be expensive.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, in Embedded Systems, memory is restricted (small in size).

Static arrays allow one to constrain any sequence without running into the problems of fragmentation.

Also, a constant static array can be placed into Read Only Memory, freeing up read/write memory.